# How can I trigger a click on a axios bound list of checkboxes on mounted in Vuejs 2?

Tags: javascript, rest, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to click() a bound checkbox in Vue.js 2. I want to click a particular dynamic checkbox in the mounted() lifecycle event, without jQuery.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div ref='users' v-for="user in users">
    <input type='checkbox' 
      :ref='user.username' 
      :id='user.id' 
      :value='user.username' />&nbsp;
      <label :for='user.id'>{{ user.name }} [username: {{ user.username }}]</label>
  </div>
  <div @click="trigger" class="trigger">Click me</div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: ''
  },
  methods: {
    popUsers: function() {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res => {
        this.users = res.data;
      });
    },
    trigger() {
        console.log(this.$refs);
        this.$refs.Karianne[0].click();//works
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.popUsers();
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(this.$refs);
    this.$refs.Karianne[0].click(); //doesn't work. i want to "click Karianne" when everything is loaded.
    }
})
</script>
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zippyferguson/we8Latcw/21/

this.$refs.Karianne[0].click(); works when you click "Click me", but not in on mounted. Too early?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this.

```
mounted() {
  Vue.nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.Karianne[0].click()
  })
}
```

I think that for some reason `$refs` is still empty at the moment of mounting the vue component. If `Vue.nextTick` doesn't help, try doing it inside a timeout callback.

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$refs.Karianne[0].click()
  }, 200)
}
```

Comment: it didn't work when I had it in mounted, but if i put in in the then of the axios.get, it worked. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zippyferguson/we8Latcw/32/

Comment: Ok, did you try delaying its execution a bit as I described above?

Comment: I believe that would work but doing in in the nextTick function is better, no?

Comment: Yes, it should work but in some cases, it doesn't that's why I mentioned a second solution. By the way, I edited the answer to the remove the need of `let self = this`. An arrow function should have `this` pointing to the Vue instance.

Comment: If you think this solved your problem, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: ''
  },
  methods: {
    popUsers: function() {
      let self = this;
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res => {
        this.users = res.data;
        self.$nextTick(function() {
          self.$refs.Karianne[0].click() //works
        })
      });
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.popUsers();
  },
  mounted: function () {
    let self = this;
    self.$nextTick(function() {
        self.$refs.Karianne[0].click() //doesn't work
    })
    }
})
```